# How could i embed an unmanaged dll? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, embed, unmanaged

In my project I reference a managed dll, that references other unmanaged dlls. I would like to know how I can embed these unmanaged dlls instead of putting them in the application's directory. I can not embed them as I would with a regular managed dll since they can not be added as a reference in my project. Thanks

Comment: What kind of unmanaged DLL(s)? [COM or traditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016683/the-difference-between-traditional-dll-and-com-dll)?

Comment: Do you not want them on the file system at all? Or just packed/extracted with the PE file? Can you give an example please?

Comment: @John Wu it is not a COM dll which is why i cant add it as a reference

Comment: @SamMakin Either way would work for me... i have the dlls embedded as resources and tried extracting them to the temp folder, but couldn't figure out how to load the dlls from there...

Comment: @JohnWu ill check that out